# Problem with reading records from a file

Tags: text-processing, solaris

I have the following problem:
Script

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

for unitcaseno in `cat /pims/nigel/UNLOAD-DB/xaa`
do
        echo "String = $unitcaseno"
        unitno=`echo $unitcaseno | cut -d'|' -f1`
        caseno=`echo $unitcaseno | cut -d'|' -f2`
        echo "Unitno = $unitno:Caseno = $caseno"
break
done
```

The file is very large so I am breaking after the first record.

```
Sample file:
  349702|            1|
  349702|            1|
  349702|            1|
 1133247|            6|
 1133247|            6|
 12708  |            1|
 12708  |            1|
 299466 |            2|
 299466 |            2|
 299466 |            2|
 299466 |            2|
 501877 |            1|
 501877 |            1|
 55871  |            9|
 55871  |            9|
 64239  |            7|
 64239  |            7|
```

Output

```
String = 349702|
Unitno = 349702:Caseno =
```

My problem is that it is not printing out the second field in either output.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 4):

The problem you're having is with the

```
for unitcaseno in `cat /pims/nigel/UNLOAD-DB/xaa`
```

structure.  This will split the file into *words*, not lines.  This is why you see `String = 349702` in the output; you're only seeing the first word and not the whole line.

Instead consider a loop similar to

```
while read unitcaseno
do
  ....
done < /pims/nigel/UNLOAD-DB/xaa
```

Now you're processing a line at a time

```
String = 349702|            1|
Unitno = 349702:Caseno =  1
```

Note you have other problems; eg extra whitespace before the `Caseno`.  But this should get you to the next step!

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thanks for that it solves my problem and the white space I can handle